# Grouping rows in .csv by data ID in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, grouping

I have a large .csv file which contains sensor data, which I would like to process in MATLAB. I cannot include the original data, but it is similar to this (with over 2000 rows):

[image]

There are other columns, but I am not interested in them.

What I would like to do in group all the data for the different courses into tables, so I would have a table for all the data from 1:12:aa, another for 5:C6:19 and so on.

I tried using the `groupsummary` function, but that just seems to give me a count of how many times each source ID is in the file. I will also be trying a look to filter the data, but I imagine there is a fast way to do it in MATLAB, and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: `groupsummary` is used to compute statistics on subsets of table, it does not give you the subset table itself. I would recommend you to look at [`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html). This will give you a list of the unique values in a set, and also all the indices in your table which match each unique value. With that it will be easy to build your group tables.

Comment: @Hoki I will do, thanks!